# Why is this javascript never executed?

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript. What I want it to do is wait until a `getJSON` has returned, in which a flag is set, and then do something. However after finding the `check` function below on SO, I can't actually get it to log `loaded` even when `flag` is true (and so `processData` is never executed). What am I doing wrong?

```
        flag = false
        $.getJSON(<url>,
            function(params){ 
                if (params){
                    flag = true;
                 }
            }
        );
 var check = function() {
        console.log("check A");

        if (flag === false) {
            console.log('still going to check');
            return setTimeout(200, check);
        }
        console.log("loaded!");
        processData();
    }
    check();
```

Comment: Change `setTimeout(200, check);` to `setTimeout(check, 200);`. The order of arguments is wrong, so `check` won't be executed a second time. Of course the real solution should be to move the `processData` call inside the `$.getJSON` callback, then you don't need a flag or use `setTimeout`.

Comment: Unless `flag` is set to false it's not going to get to the timeout anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to include that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of periodically checking for the JSON to arrive, you can use JavaScript [promise and deferred](http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics) objects to do the job for you. Below is example.

```js
var url = 'http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/';

function loadUrl(url) {
  var deferredLoad = $.Deferred();
  $.get(url, function(data, status) {
    if ('success' == status) {
      deferredLoad.resolve(data);
    }
  });
  return deferredLoad.promise();
}

function documentReady() {
  var deferredReady = $.Deferred();
  $(document).ready(function() {
    deferredReady.resolve();
  });
  return deferredReady.promise();
}

$.when(documentReady(), loadUrl(url)).then(
  function(readyRespond, data) {
    $('#content').html("Loaded page is below:" + data);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
```

Answer (score 6):

You need `setTimeout(check, 200);` rather than `setTimeout(200, check);`. You'll also have to explicitly set `flag` to false before running the function.

However, you could just go with:

```
    $.getJSON(<url>,
        function(params){ 
            if (params){
                check();
             }
        }
    );
    var check = function() {
       console.log("check A");
       console.log("loaded!");
       processData();
    }
```